How to express sin(sin(sin(sin(…sin(x+iy)))))>0 but with infinite sines
The function sin(sin(sin(…sin(x+iy)))>0 gets closer to looking like a fractal with more “sin(“ and I want to graph an expression on Desmos with infinite “sin(“ to see what it looks like. How do I do that?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

I'm afraid I have bad news for you.
Let's fix some number $z$ (your "$x + iy$"), and suppose that
$$
u = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^{[n]}(z)
$$
exists, where we define
\begin{align}
\sin^{[1]}(x) &= \sin(x) \\
\sin^{[k]}(x) &= \sin(\sin^{[k-1]}(x)) & \text{for $k > 1$}
\end{align}
In other words, $\sin^{[k]}$ denotes "sine, applied $k$ times".
Now we've supposed that the limit
$$
u = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^{[n]}(z)
$$
exists. Applying sine to both sides, we get
\begin{align}
\sin(u) 
&= \sin \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^{[n]}(z) \right)\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin \left( \sin^{[n]}(z) \right) & \text{(1)}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^{[n+1]}(z)& \text{(2)}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sin^{[n]}(z)& \text{(3)}\\
&= u& \text{(4)}\\
\end{align}
The explanations for these steps are

Because $\sin$ is continuous everywhere, we can bring it inside a limit
Applying sine $n$ times and then once more is the same as applying it $n+1$ times
As $n$ goes to infinity, so does $n + 1$
the thing on line 3 is exactly the definition of $u$.

So no matter what $z$ might be, we end up with $\sin(u) = u$. Using Desmos, you can see that the only solution to this (on the real line -- see comment below) is $u = 0$.
So your "limit function", if it exists at all, is the everywhere-zero function. More precisely, everywhere your limit exists, it's zero; at other places, it's simply undefined.
So your "limit plot" will not look very interesting.

There are complex solutions for $\sin(z)=z$. Wouldn’t that effect the graph as well?

Yes...good point. I should have mentioned that. I was thinking mostly about the real line, though, where we can see that in the limit, nothing interesting happens. Certainly for any point $q$ with $\sin(q) = q$, we have that the limit of repeatedly taking sines is also $q$. I don't know how many such points there are (I basically stink at complex analysis), but I'm guessing that they're not dense...which would still makes the plot that OP asked about not-very-interesting. I've edited to indicate that my claim only applies to the real line.

Iterated $\cos$ may be more interesting, with its real fixed point of 0.7390851332151607.

Agreed. I'm lucky OP didn't ask about that. :)

Would it be different if my function was absolute value?
